# Safe to put capacitor at I/O pin?

Tags: capacitor

I'm using a microcontroller to simply turn on and off an LED, but I want it to fade in and out. I set up the circuit in this way:

[image]

When the pin goes high, the capacitor would instantaneously draw a large amount of current as it starts to charge up, and the pin can only source up to 25mA.

I was wondering whether this is still safe to do or could it possibly damage the pin?

Comment: 1. No, this is not the best way to do this. 2. 25 mA will charge a 10 uF cap up to 5 V in 2 ms, much too fast for you to notice the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of reasons why you shouldn't do this.  Here are the ones that I can think of:

1. It won't make the LED fade in.  As others mentioned, the RC time constant is too short to be noticed.
2. You run the risk of exceeding the current on the output buffer and damaging the part.
3. You run the risk of exceeding the current on the clamping diodes on the pin and damaging the part.

Others have mentioned 1 and 2, so I will elaborate on 3.

When your device turns off, the power rail (I'm assuming 5v) will go to 0v but the capacitor will still be charged.  Inside the MCU is a diode from the pin to VCC, and another from GND to the pin.  If the cap is charged and VCC is 0v then the diode to VCC will be forward biased and start to conduct.  If the cap is large enough and the 5v rail decays quickly enough then the current flowing through this diode can be quite large.

Normally this isn't a problem, but if you try to make that cap really large (to lengthen the RC time constant) then it becomes an issue.  If the cap were really large then it would not surprise me to see several amps through that diode.

(Note:  I'm ignoring the load on the +5v rail and what it does to this problem.  Deal with it.)

As others have also mentioned, PWM is the correct thing to do here.  But let me add that the human eye has a logarithmic response, and you have to take that into account when fading in/out.

What I mean by this is that lets say that the LED is spitting out 1 mW of energy and you increase it to 2 mW.  You see something less than a doubling of of the light.  Now you change the energy from 2 mW to 4 mW.  What you see is the same step up in light as when you went from 1 mW to 2 mW.  In other words, the 2 mW increase the second time around produced the same apparent increase in light as the 1 mW the first time.

If you were going to make an LED fade in, using PWM, you don't ramp up the PWM duty cycle linearly.  You do it exponentially.  So instead of 10%, 20%, 30%, . . . 90%, 100% you do it like this:  1%, 2%, 4%, 8%, 16%, 32%, 64%, 100% (or something similar).  Fading out is done the same way, just going down.

Incidentally, this exponential fade in is exactly opposite what an RC filter would do.  That would give you something like 0%, 50%, 80%, 90%, 95%, 98%, 99%, 100% (but with voltage, not duty cycle).  So even if you managed to get an RC time constant that was long enough it still wouldn't have the required shape to look nice.

Comment: Your point 3 is specious.  Even the lowest levels of HBM (with series limiting resistor used during test) for ESD testing will easily surpass the current levels that a small cap like that can support.  Additionally, when the rails collapse the load seen by these "supporting caps" will be the parasitic loads present, i.e. the rails don't slam shut so much as they droop.

Comment: @rawbrawb  I find your comment specious.  HBM calls for a 100 pF cap charged to 1-20 kV discharged through a 1500 ohm cap.  While this can cause a very quick impulse through that diode, the total energy is not that much.  Further, that is exactly the kind of event the diode is designed to withstand-- it is not designed for continuous current.  For ex., the MSP430 is spec'd to have an abs max current through that diode of only 2 mA.  I also said that the cap has to be quite large for this to really matter.  Larger than 10 uF.  You can easily get >2mA for long enough to blow the diode.

Comment: @rawbrawb  Here is a simulation of this scenario, https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/b8qttz/protection-diode-overcurrent/.  This is a reasonable circuit given what the OP said (and didn't say).  It shows exceeding the 2 mA max current for 300 mS, with a peak of 7 mA.  It also lets you play with the values of things to see what happens.

Comment: The 2 mA given as an example should lead you to important reason why supporting the pin with the rail collapsing is a bad idea.  However, it is not because it will kill the diode, I just looked at some process data and even (4) 200 nm X 200 nm contacts to Si can support that much current and the diode underneath (N++/PW) could easily support that.  But 2 mA is totally insufficient to support any level of ESD activity, so that alone should tell you that the 2mA is not a limit of the diode but is in place for another reason.

Comment: During pin tests and simulations it's easy to see 10's of Amps (peak) and filament formation in the substrate in post event SEM's.  I've designed ESD structures/cells for IC's that are in production.  The 2 mA limit is to prevent latch-up which is really a good reason to put in your list but the diodes are fine.

Comment: @rawbrawb - Specious is such a strong word :-). You may well design ESD structures that laugh in the face of hard connected 10 uF caps. Others mightn't. A diode would have to be made of silicon on rice-pudding-skin technology to not survive a one time hit of this magnitude, but there's no guarantee that some ICs won't have a hard time with this load.

Comment: How does sophistry sound? ;)  Any I/O has to by rights handle at least it's current limited rating, so 2 mA vs. 25 mA (pin drive capability) tells you something.  And if there is ESD protection in place then it has to support massive (albeit) fast currents.  I'll leave it to you to add in the latch-up comment to get the points.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer, explains a lot. I guess I should have clarified in the question that I all the PWMs from the microcontroller are used for something else which is why I wanted to find another way to fade the LED, but I guess this wont work out to well anyways. It might just be worth it to upgrade the microcontroller to one with more PWMs. Thanks!

Comment: @Shubham Keep in mind that the PWM of this LED does not have to be accurate, only "mostly accurate".  It might be possible to do PWM in software using a combination of interrupts and timers.  The PWM frequency only needs to be about 200 Hz as well.

Comment: I did software PWM with fading some years ago, at 200Hz and about 200 brightness levels, which results in one interrupt every 25µs (a relatively high load on the 16MHz R8C I used). As for fading, I found that a quadratic curve works well, better than exponential. I had visible steps during fading at low brightness, to hide those I used a minimal rate of change, so that these steps became too fast to see.

Answer (score 4):

It won't do any damage, but it won't work.

PWM is the usual way to fade an LED.

Comment: I see, the RC time constant is too small. I'm using a PIC with 2 PWMs and unfortunately both are being used for something else...

Comment: @Shubham You can always use a timer to simulate a PWM or even make a PWN using only software

Comment: PWM for a LED can be made in Software with any GPIO pin.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to watch your current too, depending on the rise time of your I/O pin and the ESR of the cap, the inrush current into that cap might exceed the recommended current output on the pin.   Might be safer to put C10 across LED1.

The added benefit of this is your RC time constant will increase now so your fade in fade out time will increase.

Comment: Oh and pwm like leon said :)